# What is the order in which the different operators are executed in Python

Tags: python, operators

() Function calls
() Boolean And
() Assignment

() Binary + or -
() Parenthesis
() Boolean Or

() / ,   *   ,   / /  or  % 
() >,<,<>, !=,==, <=,>= 
()Unary + or -

() Slicing
() Boolean Not
() Subscription

() Exponential

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html   would be a good start

Comment: What tutorial are you using?  What are you reading that lead to this confusion?

Answer (score 4):

See the table at : http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary

Also check out the evaluation order.

- It says - *Python evaluates expressions from left to right.*
- While evaluating an assignment, *the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.*

Comment: That is because assignment is not an expression in Python, unlike other languages.  Also, exponentiation is evaluated right-to-left - try 2**3**2, you'll get 2**9, not 8**2.

Comment: These 2 are not on this list
Assignment
Parenthesis

Comment: @lhh305: It is in section http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator